# PHP registration form will not submit

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code,
HTML:

```
<div class="form-content">

                <form method="post" action="../controller/regprocess.php">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Rusername" name="Rusername" required="required" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="Rpassword" name="Rpassword" required="required" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="RfirstName" name="RfirstName" required="required" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="RlastName" name="RlastName" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="Remail" name="Remail" required="required" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input type='number' id="Rphone" name="Rphone" required="required" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit">Register</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
```

regprocess PHP:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
//connect to the database
require('../model/database.php');
//Load user functions
require('../model/functions_users.php');

//retrieve the registration details into the form
$username = $_POST['Rusername'];
$password = $_POST['Rpassword']; 

$firstName = $_POST['RfirstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['RlastName'];

$email = $_POST['Remail'];
$phone = $_POST['Rphone'];

//call the add_user() function
$result = add_user($username, $password, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phone);

//create user messages
if($result)
{
    //create a success message to display on page
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Thank you for creating an account. Please login.';
    //redirect to products.php
    header('location: ../view/login-registration.php?page=login');
}
else
{
    //create a error message to display on page
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'An error has occurred. Please try again.';
    //redirect to product_add_form.php
    header('location: ../view/login-registration.php?page=login');
}?>
```

and finally my result function:

```
    function add_user($username, $password, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phone)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstName, lastName, email, phone) VALUES (:username, :password, :firstName, :lastName, :email, :phone)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->bindValue(':firstName', $firstName);
    $statement->bindValue(':lastName', $lastName);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $statement->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}
```

I have two parent divs overlapping each other, one is hidden (registration form) until a panel is clicked and sets div active to appear on top of the login form. The active div (login form) submit button works but the 2nd form (registration form) submit button does not work.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var panelOne = $('.form-panel.two').height(),
panelTwo = $('.form-panel.two')[0].scrollHeight;

$('.form-panel.two').not('.form-panel.two.active').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.form-toggle').addClass('visible');
    $('.form-panel.one').addClass('hidden');
    $('.form-panel.two').addClass('active');
    $('.form').animate({'height': panelTwo
    }, 200);
});

$('.form-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('visible');
    $('.form-panel.one').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.form-panel.two').removeClass('active');
    $('.form').animate({
    'height': panelOne
    }, 200);
});
```

});

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? It helps to know the error when trying to work out what went wrong.

Comment: debug step by step. not the whole thing at once

Comment: Maybe somthing to do with javascript? I have two parent divs overlapping eachother, one is hidden (registration form) until a panel is clicked and sets div active to appear ontop of the login form. The un-hidden div's (login form)submit button works but the 2nd forms submit button will not.

Comment: *"Maybe somthing to do with javascript?"* - Given the id's, yeah that could very well be it and you should be posting your full code for all this, because what you posted looks fine to me, when used as pure php.

Comment: *"but the 2nd forms submit button will not."* - what second form is that?

Comment: i've updated my post to hopefully be a bit more clear - i sorta rushed the original, sorry. The 2nd, hidden, form (registration) is the one that is not submitting. The 1st form submits. Both forms are overlapped and the 2nd form is displayed on click of side panel via some javascript code which i have updated in my post.

Comment: I did a copy and paste of some of your code to get a simple start case that works.
I took you HTML code posted above and put it in a file index.html. 
In regprocess.php, I put 'echo "hello"' under start_session() and commented out the code below it.
Then when the register button was clicked, it printed "hello" on the screen as it should.
That is a very simple baseline case, but should give you something to start with. You can 
build up the JavaScript from there, and see where it starts to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.form-panel.two').not('.form-panel.two.active').on('click', function(e) {
/*e.preventDefault(); --> it looks like this is what is preventing your form submission but it is hard to tell without the full file and error log */
$('.form-toggle').addClass('visible');
$('.form-panel.one').addClass('hidden');
$('.form-panel.two').addClass('active');
$('.form').animate({'height': panelTwo
}, 200);
});
```